# Call jqXHR.Abort() from Html.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, ajax, html.actionlink

This is my action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Details", "Details", new { controller = "Patients", id = @Model.Payments.FirstOrDefault().RCMPatientID, acctHistoryRedirect = "acctInfo", defaultPaymentID = @Json.Encode(paymentID) }, new { target = "_blank", @class = "button button--primary button--sm" })
```

this is my ajax function:

```
var jqXHR;
    $(function () { 
        var xspinner = new Spinner();
        jqXHR = $.ajax({ /* complete */}) });
```

Is it possible to call `function(){ jqXHR.abort(); }` from the action link so that it doesn't run the ajax call when clicked?

Comment: Is the link navigating you away from the page? If so, do you really care about the AJAX request?

Comment: it does navigate to a new page, but when i click the link, it displays 2 loading icons instead of just one. I am trying to get one of the loading items to not display by aborting the ajax request that it is in.

Comment: Maybe the issue is how two requests (or two icons) got started/displayed in the first place? I think cancelling an already running one probably isn't the right approach here. Is there additional code you could post that might offer additional clues? Generally we like [mcve]s.

Comment: unfortunately, there's like 5 or 6 files involved and a lot of code in each one. i don't know how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example out of it. Guess I'll just have to keep looking. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file with the ajax call, `_History.cshtml`, I added this at the top:

```
@{
    string isRedirect = "";
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["acctHistoryRedirect"] != null)
    {
        isRedirect = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["acctHistoryRedirect"].ToString();
    }
}
```

add the following to the javascript section of the file:

```
<script>
var isRedirectToAcct = '@isRedirect';
.
.
.
$(function () {

        if (isRedirectToAcct == null || isRedirectToAcct == ''){
            var xspinner = new Spinner();
            $.ajax({ /*complete*/ })
    }
});
.
.
.
</script>
```

This solved my issue of two ajax calls running that resulted in two loading spinners displaying on the page.